# Read label value in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using the below code to assign the label text using javascript. It's working well. But i can't able to read the label text in code behind. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
Javascript:
==========

var lbl_total = document.getElementById('<%= lbl_total.ClientID %>');
lbl_total.innerHTML = '500';

c# code behid :
===============

string total = lbl_total.Text; //It always return "";
```

Comment: Are you firing an event which causes "Post"?

Comment: You can't use like this. You will have to use some other control like `hidden field`.

Comment: is that work for you ???

Answer (score 0):

client side changes for label will not get reflected in server side as its data is not posted to server. So the solution is to take an input hidden control and set its value with label's updated value. Below is the sample code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var total = 0;
            $('#Button1').click(function() {
                total += 150;
                $("span[id$=lbl_TotalCount]").html(total);
                $("input:hidden[id$=MyHidden]").val(total);
            });
        });                
    </script>
```

html

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_saveForm" runat="server" Text="save" CssClass="btnForm" OnClick="btn_saveForm_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_TotalCount" Style="color: #00e4ff; font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline" runat="server" Text="0">
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="MyHidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
```

full Article : [**Get label value in code behind whose text is changed via JavaScript/jQuery**](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1287/get-label-value-in-code-behind-whose-text-is-changed-via-javascript-jquery)